# fetch ids with commas in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

view.py

```
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        res = Question.objects.all()

    # queryset = super().ListAPIView(*args, **kwargs)
    if 'tag' in self.request.GET:
        # split and directly put in main query

        res = res.filter(
            Tag_name=self.request.GET['tag']
        )
    if 'order_by' in self.request.GET:
        res = res.order_by(
            self.request.GET['order_by'])

    serializer = QuestionSerializers(res, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

here I am trying to fetch question with some input tag ids and order by some input , how can I use multiple tag ids in url like

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?tag=1,2&order_by=name
```

so I get all objects with tag ids 1 and 2.

Comment: Can you post your models?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple get parameters with the same name:

```py
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?tag=1&tag=2&order_by=name
```

In your view you can access the list using the `getlist` method:

```py
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # returns empty list if no tags are provided
    tags = self.request.GET.getlist('tag')

    # you can set a default field to order_by, if no field is provided
    order_by = self.request.GET.get('order_by', 'id')  

    # convert tags, currently strings, to int
    tags = [int(tag) for tag in tags]

    # not sure about this part would need to check your models
    res = Question.objects.filter(tag__id__in=tags).order_by(order_by)
    serializer = QuestionSerializers(res, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to split values of `tag` by `,` and filter all tags with `id__in` filter like this

```
def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
    res = Question.objects.all()

    # queryset = super().ListAPIView(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.request.GET.get('tag'):
        # split and directly put in main query

        res = res.filter(
            tag_id__in=self.request.GET.get('tag').split(',')
        )
    if self.request.GET.get('order_by'):
        res = res.order_by(
            self.request.GET['order_by'])

    serializer = QuestionSerializers(res, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: do you know how will i create swagger api view for this path ?

Comment: `django-rest-swagger` by default show only params which are in your serializer. `drf-yasg` have option to set your own schema for such case.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can have a workaround(or better to say more django rest framework oriented way to achieve this) using ListAPIView of DRF like:

```
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView
class TagListAPIView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuestionSerializers
    filter_backends = (OrderingFilter)
    ordering_fields = ['name', ...any other fields you wanna put here as an option for ordering]
    ordering = 'name' #setting the default ordering
    def get_queryset(self):
        ids = self.request.query_params.get('tag', None)
        if not ids:
            return Question.objects.none() #Empty queryset
        return Question.objects.filter(id__in=ids.split(','))
```

Haven't tested the code but yeah it should be somewhere around this and this code does not do all the proper input handling if some garbage input is coming from user(which is the case manytimes).
You could write more strong code for this by incorporating django-filters and putting a id field in that filter. Which would give you all the error validation and handling.
I have provided a links to DRF's doc regarding filter, ordering and all. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter
Have a look, its great content.
Ping me if anything unclear.